# How do I fix the edges that runs around my cube from becoming really long when scaling on an axis?

Tags: modeling

I'm really new to blender, and I thought I'd make a cube for my game that has glow in the middle and edges running around it. I extruded faces inward to make the edges, but when I scale the cube in any axis the edges of the cube that face that axis becomes really long and it doesn't look good at all. Any way I can fix this? I looked around and couldn't find any solution, therefor I'm asking here. Thank you in advance!

[image: Here's the cube when I've not yet stretched it]

[image: Here's an example of the cube when I've stretched it]

[Here's the file](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=B4921BDAA38A3C6E&resid=B4921BDAA38A3C6E%2198408&authkey=APFLkXXQtigNWVI)

Comment: hello, how did you make your edges? maybe pack the images (if there are) and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I made the edges by extruding the faces of the cube inwards. I attached the file to the original question (I think) Have no idea how to attatch files really to this site really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stretch the cube without deforming the edges, you need to modify the mesh itself in *Edit* mode, because if you stretch it in *Object* mode will also change the edges width, so switch to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to have transparency, select the vertices of one side, and move them along the axis you want:

[image]

Comment: oooh. Thank you very much! :)